# How to remove redundant codes?

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

Am not sure I'm asking in the right place. I am using the [Open Xml Productivity Tool 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) and after generating codes, I usually have so much redundant code like:

```
Bold bold1 = new Bold();
Bold bold2 = new Bold();
Text1 = new Text("A");
Text2 = new Text("A");
...etc.
```

It consumes thousands of lines and is difficult for me to even navigate through.

I tried resharper:

[image: Resharper Screenshot]

but you can see the threat it is handing me (now changed to 18 hours now and am not sure it will be able to solve it).

[image: Second Screenshot]

Is there any program out there that can perform this type of refactoring fast?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you determine to be fast? You say you are running through thousands of lines of code and I imagine any resharper will be checking each line individually to determine what is redundant

Comment: 11 hours is too much. Can you specify which ReSharper version have you used and what operation did you do exactly?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply. It's about 64,000 lines of code, the time continued increasing from 18hours to not responding etc. By fast I mean at least something bearable. I'm using Resharper 7.1.3 and I'm on 6GB Ram, 2.5GHz core i5, 3MB L1 cache

Comment: Sorry, seems that stackoverflow didn't send me any notification about your answer. Please try to use @Dmitry Osinovskiy next time. If this is still actual, could you please say which operation did you try to perform in ReSharper exactly, with step-by-step description?

Comment: @DmitryOsinovskiy: Ok thanks, I was trying to do Code Cleanup. I even went on to copy out just a small portion of the code and try refactoring it, but it ended up increasing the length instead. I am still unaware of any program that can solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: @rtuner Could you please send us the code that you are trying to cleanup so we could tune the performance in the upcoming ReSharper 8.0? You can do it by creating a new request at http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/ . Thanks!